# Git using master branch for production and dev branch for dev server

Tags: git, bitbucket, laravel-forge

We're trying to switch to the Branched Workflow for git (we've been using Centralized for the most part). At the moment, the production and dev server both serve the master branch from our BitBucket git repo.

Our dev server uses Laravel Forge, and the deployment script is below. If we were to create a "dev" branch, I would like this branch to be the "main" branch for the dev server, while master will remain the main for production.

My question is, how can I modify the deployment script below, so that the dev server only serves the dev branch, so clients can sign off before me merge it into master and deploy to production?

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a branch off your master with name `dev`

Set an environment variable `serverType` to `dev` on your dev server or invoke your deploy script using

```
serverType='dev' ./deploy.sh
```

Modify your script to below-

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull
if test "$serverType" = "dev"; then
  git checkout dev
fi
```

Comment: Even simpler: `git checkout ${serverType:-master}` without `if`.